# python ошибка при поиске значения в excel

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import openpyxl as xl
import re

path = r'C:/Users/Desktop/Test_new/FindTest.xlsx'
wb = xl.load_workbook(filename=path, read_only=True)
ws = wb['страница']

for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if re.match(r'test', cell.value):
        print(cell.value)
```

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: В какой строке?

Comment: if re.match(r'test', cell.value):

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример документа. Видимо, значение ячейки не является строкой, поэтому не может быть обработано регулярным выражением.

Comment: я уже так устал от этого эксель есть простой способ весь текст вытащить из него и запихать в txt файл??

Comment: @AleksandrChirikov Можно вытащить весь текст. Просто с этого и нужно было начинать. Дело в том, что `Excel` таблица может содержать не только текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте проверку на то, что значение является строкой.

***Пример:***

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import re

# Замените путь на свой
PATH = 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/openpyxl/test.xlsx'


def main():
    wb = load_workbook(filename=PATH)
    ws = wb.active

    for row in ws.rows:
        for cell in row:
            value = cell.value

            # Замените регулярное выражение на своё
            if type(value) == str and re.match(r'test', value):
                print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```